# Creating a new line in MAILTO: Hyperlink Formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I have a hyperlink formula in excel and when you click on it, it opens up a new email message in my mail client with the information it is populating from the excel sheet. Here's the sample:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:example@mail.com?subject=Important%20Stuff&body=Hansel,%0A%0APlease%20do%20not%20eat%20the%20cookies.%0A%0AThanks,%0AGretel","Send Email")
```

This will hopefully create the message:

```
Subject: Important Stuff
Body:
Hansel,

Please do not eat the cookies.

Thanks,
Gretel
```

But it doesn't. If I use that link in HTML, the email message that is created is exactly how I want it with all the new lines (%0A).  However, clicking on that link in excel with the hyperlink function brings up the email message with all the new lines (%0A) written out as it looks in the formula.

Any ideas for getting this to work would be a huge help!

Answer (score 4):

the solution is to use `%0D%0A` instead of `%0A` in your hyperlink command.

[How to enter line break into mailto body command](http://www.cubetoon.com/2008/how-to-enter-line-break-into-mailto-body-command/)

Comment: This isn't working for me either. Is this a Mac thing? I read that using CHAR(10) will work as well, but on Macs it's CHAR(13).

Comment: ok you are using mac, this could be some kind of problem, on my windows pc it's working awesome, maybe try to only use %0D.

Comment: Yeah, that's not working either.. I'll keep looking. Thanks for your input!